# How to return array of values from evaluate method

Tags: jquery, casperjs

I'm using casper.evaluate() to get an array of data from within the page. However it seems to fail to return an array (whereas returning strings work flawlessly). What might be the issue?

For clarification: the code in evaluate is:

```
function(){ 
    return $('#id a').map(function(i, e) { 
        return $(e).attr('href'); 
    }).get(); 
}
```

The `.get()` at the end of the call is meant to get an array instead of a jQuery object. BTW, I'm sure jQuery is available in the page.

Comment: btw, my issue wasn't with this part of the code. it works fine inside a .evaluate() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need jQuery here:

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
    return [].map.call(__utils__.findAll('#id a'), function(node) {
        return node.getAttribute('href');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .get() is unneccesary.

The return without .get() forms a very nice array indeed, have a look at this jsfiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/YFsRw/

```
r = function(){ 
    return $('#id a').map(function(i, e) { 
        return $(e).attr('href'); 
    }); 
}

var p = r();

// p servers as a nice array :)
for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    document.write(p[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: your fiddle actually uses `.get()`. but although it's Array-like, it's not an array and I don't know how (if) it would come from the page context to casperjs context.

Comment: sorry, sth must go wrong, as i tested fiddle with and without .get(), seems the earlier was saved, anyhow, both worked :)

Comment: no :( i realized only later it relates to casper. i am sorry for the disrespect of Your time.

Answer (score 0):

### [**.toArray()**](http://api.jquery.com/toarray/) is what you're looking for.

> **.toArray()**   [Returns: Array]
>
> Description: Retrieve all the elements contained in the jQuery set, as an array.

```
function(){ 
    return $('#id a').map(function(i, e) { 
        return $(e).attr('href'); 
    }).toArray(); 
}
```

---

**Alternatively**, there is also [`$.makeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/), which works on a broader level, with more than just *jQuery element sets*, and is called in a static manner.

```
function(){ 
    return $.makeArray(
        $('#id a').map(function(i, e) { 
            return $(e).attr('href'); 
        })
    ); 
}
```

(But **`.toArray()`** seems more fitting and clearer in this case.)

---

See [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434145/difference-between-toarray-and-makearray-in-jquery) for a comparison of the two.