# Difference between toArray and makeArray in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to convert the DOM element as an collections of object. But I don't know what the main difference between toArray() and makeArray()

**HTML**

```
<div id="firstdiv">
   <div>foo1</div>
   <div>foo2</div>
   <div>foo3</div>
</div>
```

I used the following code to convert the nodes to an array:

**JQUERY**

```
console.log($("#firstdiv > div").toArray());
console.log($.makeArray($("#firstdiv").html()));
```

I can't quite understand the difference between them, and I've searched for this question but not found any clear explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to jQuery documentation:

`toArray` is a method on jQuery Object (which is wrapper around a set of DOM elements). This method extracts members of this set of DOM elements to javascript Array:

```
jQuery('.some-class').toArray() -> [ dom_el_1, dom_el_2, dom_el_3, ... ]
```

`makeArray` (which is a "static method" on jQuery object) takes [array-like object](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/) (jQuery, arguments, nodeList, ...) and constructs a proper javascript Array from it, so you can call methods of Array on the result:

```
// returns a nodeList (which is array like item) but not actual array
// you can't call reverse on int
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);
arr.reverse(); // use an Array method on list of dom elements
$(arr).appendTo(document.body);
```

In summary, `toArray` transforms *jQuery element set* to javascript `Array`, `makeArray` transforms any *array like object* to javascript `Array`.

Comment: Is there a difference between `.get()` and `.toArray()`?

Comment: .toArray() and .get() both return Array of nodes in jQuery result set. .get() accepts optional index parameter in which case it returns node at the `index` position or `undefined` if index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is:

`toArray()` is `DOM Element Methods` and you can only used it on dom elements. while `makeArray(object)` can be used on your custom objects.

There is no other differences they are mostly same and return plain array object.

**Example**

You have any custom object:

```
function Person(name,age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
var obj=new Person('abc',1);
```

now to use both function:

```
jQuery.makeArray(obj).length;  //would return 1
```

while:

```
obj.toArray().length;  //through the error function not defined
```

and

```
obj.length; //return undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned already `toArray()` is for jQuery objects.

`$.makeArray()` is similar to JS `Array.prototype.slice.call()` or `[].slice.call()` for short, though the latter instantiates an object with `[]`

But there's a difference when processing POJOs with excessive `length` value

**Examples**

1.

```
$.makeArray({ 0:'a', 1:'b', length:1 })
// ["a"]

[].slice.call({ 0:'a', 1:'b', length:1 })
// ["a"]
```

2.

```
$.makeArray({ 0:'a', 1:'b', length:4 })
// { 0:'a', 1:'b', length:4 } // WUT?

[].slice.call({0:'a', 1:'b', length:4})
// ["a", "b", undefined, undefined]
```

3.

```
$.makeArray({12:'a', 13:'b', length:1})
// { 12:'a', 13:'b', length:1 } // WUT?

[].slice.call({12:'a', 13:'b', length:1})
// [undefined]
```

4.

```
$.makeArray({ 0:'a', 2:'b', length:2 })
// { 0:'a', 2:'b', length:2 } // WUT?

[].slice.call({ 0:'a', 2:'b', length:2 })
// ["a", undefined]
```

---

Thus `$.makeArray()` simply returns the input object whenever a key with particular index is not found.

It will work fine only when converting array-like objects with proper number of items in the array e.g. function's `arguments`, `nodeList`, jQuery collections, etc.

Comment: You have a couple of small mistakes in this answer. First don't use the word POJO. They're called array-like objects. Second, [].slice.call() doesn't fill in empty slots with `undefined`. Only Array.from() does that. [].slice.call() leaves them empty.